# 2 way binding ngModel changes is also reflecting in its assigned temp variable(assigned on page load)

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, 2-way-object-databinding, ngmodel

I have a 2 way binding model which i am assigning to a temp variable on page load. But the temp variable also taking the NgModel changes.

```
this.questionService.getAll(this.id, this.bcID).subscribe(_result => {
      this.questions = _result.data.filter(x => x.isDeleted === false);
      this.tempQuestions = _result.data.filter(x => x.isDeleted === false);
    });
```

Using KEndo UI Grid

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView"
              [height]="550"
              [skip]="gridState.skip"
              (edit)="editHandler($event)"">
```

```
this.gridView = process(this.questions, this.gridState);
```

Comment: Try assigning your `this.tempQuestions` as a deep copy of `this.questions`. 
Deep copy explained partly here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript

Comment: @Jojofoulk Thank you sir. It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically both the variables `this.questions` and `this.tempQuestions` are pointing to the same objects. To ensure changes doesn't reflect back to `this.tempQuestions` do a deep clone of the `this.questions` object.

This will help

```
this.questionService.getAll(this.id, this.bcID).subscribe(_result => {
  this.questions = _result.data.filter(x => x.isDeleted === false);
  this.tempQuestions = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.questions));
});
```